# Spring @Scheduled annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cron, spring-scheduled

How can I use @Scheduled annotation of spring dynamically?

```
CronTrigger(String expression, TimeZone timeZone)
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronTrigger.html#CronTrigger-java.lang.String-java.util.TimeZone-

As I have multiple timeZones in database, how can I pass them dynamically?

I tried this in my code:

```
TimeZone timezone = null;
String timezone1 = null;
public SchedulerBean(String timezone2) 
{
     this.timezone1 = timezone2;
  //constructor
}

@Scheduled(cron="0 0 8 * * ?", zone =timezone.getTimeZone(timezone1) ) //Error at this line
public void sendQuestionNotif() 
{
  //......code
}
```

Here is the **error** I am getting,

```
*Type mismatch: cannot convert from TimeZone to String*
```

Please help me. Because I want to trigger *cron* based on *timezones*. TIA.

Answer (score 5):

Annotation parameters cannot be set dynamically. You can do it programmatically, like this

```
class Scheduler implements Runnable {
    public Scheduler(TaskScheduler scheduler, String timezone, String cron) {
        scheduler.schedule(this, new CronTrigger(cron, TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone)));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If I use ur answer, then do I need to still use @Scheduled(cron="cronExpression", Timezone timezone) on the method which does work for me based on cron expression?

Comment: No, you dont. But you can create Scheduler as a bean from context

Comment: Can you provide the solution you got ? it would be very helpful for me and for other users