# How to load a cron expression from db and reschedule it with Spring?

Tags: spring, dynamic, cron, task, scheduled-tasks

I'm using Spring scheduling to have batches in my application.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${batch.name|0 0 21 * * ?}")
public void restart() { }
```

Values are load from a properties file and default value from the @Scheduled annotation parameter.

Now, I would like to be able to load a cron value from database (so from an object) without using Quartz library, only with the default Spring scheduler.

Does someone know if and how it is possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by following this :
[Spring @Scheduled annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651196/spring-scheduled-annotation)

and this :
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/scheduledexecutorservice.html

Comment: Can you please explain how did you find solution, some sample code.

Comment: Sorry for that long time reply. I do not have any access to the code anymore. I'll post a code sample if/as soon as I can.