# Scheduled task with DB driven execution date

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

**Problem:**

I'm wondering if it's possible in Spring to schedule jobs (via UI in an application to start on certain date like 2018/1/15 11AM UTC).

**Scenario & clarification:**

1. An user (let's say an admin) wants to schedule a job - sending emails
2. The job is scheduled to be executed on a certain date (Monday 1/15 @11 AM)
3. Next week he wants the same job to be executed on (Tuesday 1/23 @10 AM) - execution date is not deterministic - it can be different every week. I also want to track in the database for what date was the job scheduled.
4. The job is persisted in the database with date when the job is supposed to be executed and with all business data that are relevant to execute the task.

**Question:**

What keywords should I look for to find hits how to achieve such an effect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066501/how-to-load-a-cron-expression-from-db-and-reschedule-it-with-spring

Comment: Use cron and poll from DB to find next date to send emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring Batch in your application. It provides **TaskScheduler**, which you can configure in xml. You can discover its capabilities to suit your needs. I did basic things with online tutorial.