# fetch cron expression from database

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot and hibernate and have issues scheduling a cron task using values existing in database. Now I'm reading values from properties file it is working fine. 
I defined property in application property file: `cron.expression=* * * ? * *` and used in the class `@Scheduled(cron="${cron.expression}")`.

but instead of getting values from properties file, I want to get them from database table.can some one share any sample code

Comment: This is your solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651196/spring-scheduled-annotation

Comment: Can i get little more details on that. I am not able to follow the above example

Comment: can son one help me on this